# SVG Matrix containing some alphabets with numbers

Tags: matrix, svg

I got the SVG text as below:

```
<g transform="matrix(4.1421333333838E-17,-0.146223085867596,0.146377578981288,4.14650973586637E-17,1490.38414123906,383.091795750625)">
  <text font-family="Arial" font-size="58.67" fill="#000000">some text here</text>
</g>
```

Wanted to know what is the significance of this E-17 here("matrix(4.1421333333838**E-17**")? I am trying to get the x,y coordinates of from the matrix. I know how to get the x, y coordinates if there are pure numbers in matrix. But I didn't get how to interpret the E-17 here for the calculation of x,y coordinates. Could anyone please help?

Comment: `anythingE-17` is a zero. That's machine precision error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't write 10<sup>-17</sup> very easily SVG uses [E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)

1E-17 is the same as 1 x 10<sup>-17</sup>